# HTTP: difference Request Property and POST - Parameters

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

i am currently trying to send a POST-method to a simple PHP webservice via an android application using the HttpURLConnection-class. Multiple tutorials use the buffered writer class to write the params into the http-body, but the HttpURLConnection also has a setRequestProperty() method which adds a key-value-pair to the connection. Apparently they are not used for the same purpose, but what is the difference(i have also checked google, but didnt find an answer to that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setRequestProperty()` is used to set HTTP headers (like `Content-Type`):

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

But to set POST parameters you need to url-encode them and write the resulting string (converted to byte stream) to the `OutputStream` obtained from `HttpURLConnection` instance.

For example, to send `a` with value `1` and `b` with value `2` as POST parameters, you could do the following:

```
final String urlEncodedString = "a=1&b=2";
final byte[] bytesToWrite = urlEncodedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
conn.getOutputStream().write(bytesToWrite);
```

Here, `conn` is an instance of `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank you, thats all i wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using too old way of making request to the server. 
Try to use some library that will reduce many unnecessary codes like loading to buffer reader and converting process,, rather i recommend you to use volley library, please read the google documentation about it.
You can create a custom JSONObjectReuqest and override the getParams method, or you can provide them in the constructor as a JSONObject to be put in the body of the request.

Like this (I edited your code):

```html
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("key", "value");
obj.put("key2", "value2");
// add whatever you want

RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,SPHERE_URL,obj,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             System.out.println(response);
             hideProgressDialog();
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: i already read about the volley-library, but for the sake of learning i wanted to do it the oldfashioned way. thank you for your suggestion though :)